# Three.js : How to return the script of a 3D Object?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm playing with *three.js* and especially the Editor where you can attach Script on 3D object.
In Unity 3D you can access a script by using something like :

```
targetGameObject.GetComponent (scriptName).targetVariable;
```

How can you do this with *three.js*?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Did you try to search [three.js api documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html) for such functionality?

Comment: There are no scripts in three.js, you are comparing two very different technologies, Unity is a game engine, three.js is a library. Your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, "Scripts" aren't a fundamental component of ThreeJS -- not in the same way as they are in Unity3D. i.e., The "scripts" in ThreeJS Editor would be better off named "scripting code" or something like that. When you publish your app, these script functions get exported to JSON as strings and get evaluated upon their associated events -- but no tangible "Script" object/component actually results from them.

In other words, the "Scripts" you're referring to in Unity3D would be something you would have to build out yourself or use an existing library.

Comment: Thank you msun, it was the answer i was looking for !